# JQuery Slide Down Not Pull All the Contain Down

Tags: jquery, css

I plan to to make a slide down NOT to pull the below container down, but it doesn't do so.  I try to set the slide down layer on the top of the below container, so that when it is slide down, it will cover the below container, but some how it doesn't work.

Please give me a hand.  Thank you!

[Live Code](http://jsfiddle.net/ogv7fqmy/1/)

JS

```
$('#open').click(
        function()
            {
                $('#login form').slideToggle(600);
                $(this).toggleClass('close');
            }

    ) //end click
```

CSS

```
#login .close {

    background-color: rgb(110,138,195); 
}

#open:hover {
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgb(110,138,195); 
}

#login form {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    display: none;  
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
#login label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align:right;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    color: rgb(58,80,123);
}
#login input {
    font-size: 14px;    
}
#login #button {
    margin-left: 50px;  
}
#open{color: red}
form{z-index:100}
.below{z-index:1}
```

HTML

```
<p></p>
<div id="login">
<p id="open">Login</p>
<form>
    <p>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password">Password: </label>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" >
    </p>
</form>
</div>
<p class="below">
    I remember writing a story about Halle Berry in college that included a mention of her abusive marriage. “Leave smoke” running away, she said at the time recounting her mother’s advice on handling men who mistreat women. For whatever reason, that quote always stuck with me especially as I learned of friends dealing with unhealthy relationships. Back then, I wondered why they stayed. But as I got older I began to understand, especially when I became one of those women who stayed waaaay past a relationship’s expiration date. And like many other women, I made excuses and didn’t know when enough was enough. Over time and with the help of friends and family who’ve been through similar situations, I learned the major deal breakers to look out for. Yes, we’re talking MAJOR. </p>
```

Comment: Want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ogv7fqmy/3/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `position` css rule for `form` to make it stable.
Try this

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ogv7fqmy/6/)

```
#login form {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; /* Remove */
    display: none;  
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    position:absolute;  /* Added */
    left:0; /* Added */
    width:100%; /* Added */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dhaval, Fallenreaper and Mohamed!  It works like a champ!

Answer (score 1):

you need to set your form to absolute position like so in css

```
#thisform{
    position:absolute;
}
```

see [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ogv7fqmy/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You need do do like i had in this  update:   http://jsfiddle.net/ogv7fqmy/7/

I added in the css:    `div#login form { position: absolute;}`